# How to solve congruence with two variables x and y

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm having trouble solving the following congruence:

$$2x + 2y ≡ 0 \pmod{7}.$$

What I've tried so far is writing the congruence as follows:  since the remainder is $0,$ we know $7$ is divisible by $2x + 2y,$ so $2x + 2y = 0 + 7k,$ and I got pretty much stuck on this step, so any further help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since $\gcd(2,7)=1$, so from this you can further conclude that $x+y \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$. Without any other information about $x$ and $y$ this is the best you can conclude.

Comment: $7|2x+2y=2(x+y)\implies7|2$ or $7|x+y$.  But $7\not|2$, so this means $7|x+y.$  Conversely,  $7|x+y\implies7|2x+2y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $4$,
$$8x+8y\equiv x+y\equiv0\mod{7}$$
Hence 
$$y\equiv -x\mod{7}$$
$$\therefore y=-x+7k$$
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I guess you multiplied by $4$ because that's the inverse of $2 \pmod 7$

Comment: Could you explain please how did you get from **8x + 8y** to **x + y**?

Comment: Because $8\equiv1\mod{7}$

Answer (score 0):

$7 | 2x+2y =2(x+y) \implies 7|2 $ or $7|x+y$.  But $7\not|2$, so this means $7|x+y$.

Conversely, $7|x+y\implies7|2x+2y$.